# how to verify input field type string that have the pattern of JSON date

Tags: java, regex

I have string that i get as input which contain json date in format `/Date(1234043600000)/`
my question is how can I verify that the input is exactly with the json date format ?

I guess I should use /[0-9] / but how I should do it for all the date pattern?

Comment: JSON doesn't have date type, date formatting in json is rather a facility of the library you are using (Jackson, Gson...)

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't actually have a native `Date` type like JavaScript does. It uses strings for that. However, it looks like you are using a JSON string that matches up the string Date with a UNIX timestamp. To match that you'd do this:

```
/Date\([\d]+\)/
```

Comment: You can simplify `[\d]` to just `\d`

Comment: Thanks , I want to check it and when i put it like this I have error in the brackets Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher('/Date\(\d+\)/'); any idea?